# Grep/Awk part of directory name to variable iteratively

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I am trying to get part of a directory name saved to a variable so that I can add it to the beginning of a file name.

This is what I have so far:

```
var=1
CH=`ls | awk '/[0-9]{2}(?=_.*)/ {if (NR=$var) print $0}'`
echo $CH
```

A folder name looks like `01_Startup`. But the echo is blank. I can't figure this out. Does anyone know if this is possible with a shell script? I'm not quite sure the order of |'s and how to combine commands. Thanks.

Tree:

```
Benu-master
|
|--Chapter_02_Startup
|--|--01_Source_tree
|--|--02_Console
|--|--03_DEBUG
```

And so on.

Comment: Question says `folder name looks like 01_Startup` but your picture shows folder name as `Chapter_02_Startup`. which one is correct?

Comment: Also you want to put prefx `02_` for all the files in the chapter sub folder or just for `*_DEBUG` file only?

Comment: @anubhava I explained below that I made a mistake, and meant to say I want the folder `Chapter_02_Startup`. I want to prefix each `iso` file in the sub-folder. The .iso's are names like `01_Source_tree.iso`, and `02_Console` and so on.

Comment: So iso file should become `03_01_Source_tree.iso` right?

Comment: @anubhava No, `02_01_Source_tree.iso`, because its parent folder is `Chapter_02_Startup`.

Comment: Ok got it, let me attempt one solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for c in Chapter_*; do
    v=${c#Chapter_}
    v=${v%%_*}
    echo chapter $c has number $v   # more chapter-processing code here
done
```

As an aside, [avoid parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Replacing `(pwd)` with my variable that holds the Chapter name, it works! For some reason it works on every folder except folder two. All the other folders are `Chapter_##_xxx`, whereas Chapter two is like `Chapter_##_xxx_xxx`. It seems that this doesn't work when another underscore follows. Any idea why? I can just rename that folder, but I'm curious why it fails there.

Comment: The `${var%pattern}` substitution substitutes the shortest possible pattern, whereas `${var%%pattern}` substitutes the longest match.  Updated the answer to permit multiple underscores.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` does not support `PCRE` so that positive lookahead is not going to work. Also, the `bash` variables cannot be called in to `awk` like that.

What I am seeing from your requirement can be met with `bash` built in string substitution.

```
$ var=01_Startup
$ echo "${var%_*}"
01
```

You can use `find` to gather list of directories and use string substitution.

```
find . -type d | while read -r dir; do echo "$dir ---> ${dir%_*}"; done
```

Comment: Well, I need to be able to run the command iteratively. I am recursively compiling programs, so I need a counter so I can move onto the next sub-directory. The way I have it set up: `buildall.sh` is in the main directory, along with 8 other folders. Each of those 8 folders has anywhere from 1-6 sub-folders that contain programs to be compiled. I want to take the beginning number from those sub-folders and add it to its program.

Comment: So, sub-folders have numbers, does the folders also have numbers? Can you do `tree main folder` and put the output in your question?

Comment: There's over 6000 files, so the output is much too large for here. It's too large for the terminal even! I've put a skeleton of it in my first post. I am only trying to get the number from the top directories (like Chapter_02_Startup). I realize before I said I was trying to get the number from the lowest directories, that was a mistake...

Comment: @SeanHeiss Thanks for the edit. So even if you capture the number from top directory, how are you planning to use it? Or is that also a question? :)

Comment: I'm trying to put that number into the beginning of the `iso` file. Right now I have it so the `iso` has the same name as it's folder (like 03_DEBUG), but I want it to be like `02_03_DEBUG`. As you might imagine, each of the Chapter folders start from one, so when the .iso's are all together, they get mixed in with ones from other folders. So I want to prepend the Chapter number so they're all ordered nicely. :) I know how I'm going to prepend it, I just don't know how to get it in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

Try this find command with awk:

```
find Chapter* -name "*.iso" -type f | awk -F'/' '{
   split($1, a, "_");
   system("mv " $0 " " $1 "/"  a[2] "_" $2)
}'
```

Comment: Thank you, but tripleee beat you. :)

Comment: Whatever works for you eventually what matters is getting your problem solved :)